# Increase spacing in list

Tags: spacing, lists

So I've been trying for a while now on how to replicate this listing below

[image: model]

And so far all I've been able to do is get the vertical spacing and custom enumeration right like so

[image] (Ignore the fact that it's not the same font)

Here's the code for it so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\roman{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength\itemsep{0.5em}   
\item Proposition 1\quad Aliquam viverra molestie purus LAN:
\item Proposition 2\quad Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \end{enumerate}
\item Proposition 3 Aliquam viverra molestie purus
\item Proposition 4 Aliquam viverra molestie purus
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The `\quad` commands seem to replicate what the first list is looking like so I've tried many ways to make the second level items to align vertically with them but never managed to do so.

Comment: have a look at the answer the roman numbering was not starting at `i`  --is corrected also

Comment: I changed the tags and title of your question, since your questions seems to be about a "list"  rather than a "listing". (The latter is usually used in the context of program code/verbatim text which does not seem to be the case in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With automatically numbered propositions:

[image]
(Red lines indicate margins)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={Proposition \arabic*\,},labelwidth=\widthof{Proposition 9 }, leftmargin =\labelwidth+\labelsep]
\item Aliquam viverra molestie purus LAN:
\item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*,leftmargin=\widthof{iii\, }]
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \end{enumerate}
\item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
\item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry since it doesn't how in the image I posted, but this code aligns the text all the way to the left which ignores my set margin inside a document. Is there a way to improve it?

Comment: @VinnieJonny: I dind' pay enough attention to the left margin. I have updated my answer accordingly and hope it now suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The following option will do the trick

```
\begin{enumerate}[align=left, leftmargin=3.5cm]
```

and for the roman numerals add `\label=roman*` in the options

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\roman{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
\setlength\itemsep{0.5em}   
\item Proposition 1\quad Aliquam viverra molestie purus LAN:
\item Proposition 2\quad Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*,align=left, leftmargin=3.5cm]
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \item Aliquam viverra molestie purus
    \end{enumerate}
\item Proposition 3 Aliquam viverra molestie purus
\item Proposition 4 Aliquam viverra molestie purus
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```